# Is there a way to make testthat search recursively?

Tags: r, testthat

When my R package directory structure has R files directly in the tests folder

```
.
+--Projroot
+---- R
|     -- routine1.R
|     -- routine2.R
+---- tests
      -- test_routine1.R
      -- test_routine2.R
```

`testthat` catches the `test_*.R` files, but when the tests themselves depend on a multitude of files, it's cleaner to have test subdirectories

```
.
+--Projroot
+---- R
|     -- routine1.R
|     -- routine2.R
+---- tests
      |
      +---- test_routine1
      |     -- test_routine1.R
      |     -- help_file11
      |     -- help_file12
      +---- test_routine2
            -- test_routine2.R
            -- help_file21
            -- help_file22
```

Just running `devtools::test()` does not catch the `test_*.R` files in inner directories.

Is there a way to make `testthat` search recursively?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`devtools::test()` calls `testthat::test_dir`.

`testthat::test_dir` finds which are the files to test with `testthat:::find_test_scripts`. And this function does not look recursively inside the folder, so natively no, `testthat` won't be able to test inside inner directories.

You can still run your tests this way, though :

```
my_test <- list.files(path = "tests", pattern = "test_|help_", recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)
lapply(my_test, test_file)
```

Comment: Collect the "test_.R" files, anywhere they are inside "tests", and pass them to testthat. That's a good idea. But testthat conveniently runs its assertions in the `tests/testthat` directory, hence if you have a `load(file="x.rda")` (because you had run, e.g., `x = c(5, 7)` followed by `save(x, file="x.rda")`), the "x.rda" file would be located. Now it seems that an option to insert the path to locate each given file needs to be written. It's not a big deal, but I'm wondering if you are suggesting a really clean solution.

Comment: Hi, this is indeed not a clean solution, but a way to bypass the native behavior of testthat ;)

Comment: Isn't this discouraging proper modularization of tests as well?